# javascript contains not working on chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to find specific text inside textbox using jquery or javascript but it`s not working on chrome

**Senerio:**
i want to add .0 after string but if .0 or .5 etc already exist then do not add .0 after string

```
$("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtquantity").blur(function() {
                    var stringvalue = $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtquantity").val();
                    if (!stringvalue.contains('.0')) {
                        var result = stringvalue + ".0";
                        stringvalue = result;
                        $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtquantity").val(stringvalue);

                    }
                    });
```

Comment: You might have to include a polyfill for the contain function. The MDN site has one ready to go: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/contains

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a cross browser solution yet to use [`String.prototype.contains`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/contains).

You can use a regular expression though to check if it fits the end of your string

Replace

```
if (!stringvalue.contains('.0')) {
```

By

```
if (!stringvalue.match(/\.[0-9]+$/)) {
```

Also even though it were cross browser, `String.prototype.contains` wouldn't do what you want as you have to cover the cases for any digit sequence behind the mantisse. It would require you to loop through each of the 10 use cases (from 0 to 9) as `contains` only accepts a search string and an optional start position.

An even weirder use case is if your number only ends with  `"."` which is a parsable float in JavaScript...

In this case you could use a greedy regex to do this:

```
if (!stringvalue.match(/\.[0-9]*$/)) {
```